# Extending Java Class with Scala Trait

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, traits

I would like to define a class `ContextItem` as the extension of java class `Predicate` with a trait `Confidence`.

Confidence is a simple trait which simply adds a confidence field to whatever it extends.

```
trait Confidence{
  def confidence:Double
}
```

I am defining my `ContextItem` class by simply stating:

```
class ContextItem extends Predicate with Confidence{}
```

But attempting to compile this yields...

```
com/slug/berds/Berds.scala:11: error: overloaded method constructor Predicate with     alternatives:
  (java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.String])com.Predicate <and>
  (java.lang.String,<repeated...>[com.Symbol])com.Predicate <and>
  (java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList[com.Symbol])com.Predicate <and>
  (com.Predicate)com.Predicate <and>
  (com.Term)com.Predicate <and>
  (java.lang.String)com.Predicate
 cannot be applied to ()
class ContextItem(pred:Predicate) extends Predicate with Confidence{
             ^
```

This seems like a trivial example, so what's going wrong?

Predicate (which is not mine) looks like:

```
/** Representation of predicate logical form. */
public class Predicate extends Term implements Serializable {
    public Predicate(String n) {
        super(n);
    }
    public Predicate(Term t) {
        super(t);
    }
    public Predicate(Predicate p) {
        super((Term)p);
    }
    public Predicate(String n, ArrayList<Symbol> a) {
        super(n, a);
    }
    public Predicate(String n, Symbol... a) {
        super(n, a);
    }
    public Predicate(String n, String... a) {
        super(n, a);
    }
    @Override
    public Predicate copy() {
        return new Predicate(this);
    }
}
```

Neither Predicate nor any of its ancestors implements confidence.

Comment: Could we see the `Predicate` class? Does it implement the `confidence` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is listing all the constructors of `Predicate`, and informing you that you're not using any of them. The default is to use a parameterless constructor, which doesn't exist here. The syntax to call, for example, the `(String)` super-constructor, would be

```
class ContextItem extends Predicate("something") with Confidence
```

or

```
class ContextItem(str: String) extends Predicate(str) with Confidence
```

Also, at the moment your `def confidence` is an abstract method, so won't compile until you give it a definition. If you intended the trait to add a writable `confidence` field then this is what you want instead:

```
var confidence: Double = 0.0
```